# Hard links in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, symlink, hardlink

is there any way to create hard links in windows xp ? i came across [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link but it says minimum vista is needed , any way to do it without using link magic software ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
**fsutil hardlink create** NewFilename ExistingFilename

For details see Microsoft documentation:
 http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fsutil_hardlink.mspx?mfr=true

Additionally if you need to programmatically do that, you can use CreateHardLink function.

```
//C++ sample
CreateHardLink( _T(“c:\\masterfile.dat”),    // Source File
            _T(“c:\\LinkToMaster.dat”),  // Link name
            NULL );    // Security attributes
```

For details see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363860(v=vs.85).aspx
http://weseetips.com/tag/createhardlink/